# Can't remove right margin and it grows as div width shrinks

Tags: html, css, margin

This seems to be a pretty standard situation but the HTML/CSS is behaving oddly.  I'm in the process of building a profile page for a game and am also looking at mobile responsiveness.  I can't seem to get the right-margin to go away.  It's not a problem in portrait mode (using a Chrome mobile emulator extension) but in landscape, the div + margin is too wide and a scrollbar appears.

HTML:

```
<div class="userProfile" style="display:none">
    <div class="profileTop">
        <div class="profilePicture">
            <img src="somepicture.png"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="profileName"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.profileTop {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 12%;
    margin: 0;
}

.profilePicture {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12vw;
}

.profilePicture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.profileName {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-family:Stencil;
    font-size: 1.3em    ;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: white;
    left: 20%;
    top: 35%;
}
```

What's odd is that if I decrease the width of the "profileTop" class, the right margin grows so that the whole thing is the same width.  Any help?

[image]

EDIT:  I can get a workable solution by reducing the width of "userProfile" but it's still bothering me that this won't work as originally intended.

EDITx2: The margin also exists on the "userProfile" div.  I suppose the "profileTop" div is following its parent somehow but even if I add margin-right: 0 attributes to both divs, the margin is still there.  The parent of "userProfile" is the body.

Comment: Side note, images are self closing, so `<img src="somepicture.png"></img>` should be just `<img src="somepicture.png" />` or `<img src="somepicture.png">`

Comment: Can you add a codepen demo?

Answer (score 0):

Error in HTML code, you don't need a closing tag for image.

Secondly, you can use media queries to achieve that. Media queries even have an option for landscape and it's really easy to use. Good luck

```
@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

P.S. Use codepen or jsFiddle second time, it will be WAY MORE simpler to help you.

EDIT: Added media queries example

Comment: I probably wasn't clear but I'm already using a media query.  The margin is there regardless of whether I'm in landscape or portrait.

Comment: Can you add everything you have to jsFiddle? That would be way easier

Comment: Oh, I see Faraz Sh. just answered your question. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a more specific selector to override the initially-assigned CSS attribute.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  div.userProfile div.profileTop {
    margin-right:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Isn't "profileTop" more specific than whatever is initially-assigned anyway?

Comment: div.profileTop is more specific than profileTop. Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: I understand that div.profileTop is more specific but .profileTop alone should be sufficient since the only attributes on the div prior to assigning css via .profileTop would be those inherited from parent classes, which as I understand it, would be replaced by whatever attributes I gave .profileTop.

Here's the jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s1hewL2b/

Comment: That is not a margin-right. You have set the width to 70%, so the rest of the unavailable space is shown in orange.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "unavailable" space.  Based on the way I set it up, "profileTop" had a left attribute of 15% and a width of 70%, so there should have been an extra 15% of available space (not unavailable).  Because I'm using % and not vw, it should be based on the width of the container, which is the "userProfile" div (correct me if that's wrong), which has a width of 100vw.  In Chrome, when I go to the box model section that shows margin, padding, etc., and I click on margin, the orange part gets highlighted so Chrome is saying that the orange is in fact margin.